# TYPO3 image resize and crop

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Is there a way to resize and crop an image within a 'Text and Images' element using typoscript?

I have used this in the past to give custom wraps to an Images Only element by setting the image layout:

```
# Get default settings for images
temp.image < tt_content.image.20
# Define new layout
tt_content.image.20 = CASE
tt_content.image.20 {
  key.field = layout
  default < temp.image
  1 < temp.image
  100 < temp.image
  100 {
    imageStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="gallery"><ul>|</ul></div>
    renderMethod = ul
    rendering {
      ul {
        oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = <li>|</li>
      }
    }
    layout.default.value = ###IMAGES###
  }
}
# Set defaults also for TEXTPIC
tt_content.textpic.20 = < tt_content.image.20.default
```

Is there a way to perhaps modify this same technique to include a set width and height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep in mind this will do only for CSC only. FSC uses fluid-templates instead of typoscript.
but the usage should be the same: in FSC look for the appropiate partial, in CSC look for the IMAGE object (should be in temp.image for your example). then you can find the usage of width and height of the record or the default-max sizes for images.
there you can append an override with your values conditioned on your selected layout.

In **FSC** you can find the partial `EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Mediagallery.html`, copy it and enhance the pathes.
At the end of that file you can find the section `media`.
depending on your layout you can modify it like this:

```
<f:section name="media">
    <f:if condition="{layout} == 1">
    <f:then>
    <f:media
        file="{column.media}"
        width="200c"
        height="200c"
        alt="{column.media.alternative}"
        title="{column.media.title}"
    /></f:then>
    <f:else>
    <f:media
        file="{column.media}"
        width="{column.dimensions.width}"
        height="{column.dimensions.height}"
        alt="{column.media.alternative}"
        title="{column.media.title}"
    /></f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:section>
```

The **CSC** solution (for 7.6) would be to wrap the width (and height) attributes:

```
tt_content.image.20 {
  maxW.override {
    override = 200c
    override.if {
      equals.field = layout
      value = 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Attention!**  the field *layout* is used otherwise in 'text and image'. you might use another field (e.g. *section_frame*),
the construct with override the override is neccessary to add to the existing functionality.

Comment: I know I can use this: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Imgresource/Index.html But I don't know where to put it to make it work?

Comment: I tried using the typoscript exactly as you have it, but it has no effect?

Comment: have a look in the TSOB (TypoScriptObjectBrowser). you  might find another width attribute at tt_content.image.20.1.file.width which may need also an override.

Comment: Perfect thank you! To make it work I changed it to: `1.file.width.override`